# Issues with rails gems all the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

[error when generating model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFCcg.png)[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSVmW.png)

When I try to do a rails s I get the following error.

I have to do a 
rvm gemset empty
and reinstall my gems very often.
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

looks like your sqlite db is incompatible, `sqlite3 --version` should tell you something like at my machine:

`3.25.2 2018-09-25 19:08:10 fb90e7189ae6d62e77ba3a308ca5d683f90bbe633cf681865365b8e92792d1c7`

if your version is much older, say 2016 or 2017, then try updating sqlite3 first before you reinstall the ruby gem.